# How to use IF EXISTS to check whether table exists before removing data in that table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I wanted to check whether a table exists before deleting the values inside the table. In SQL Server we can do as simple as so :

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_to_be_edited')
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM table_to_be_edited;
END;
```

but how do we do it in MySQL ?

I am using MySQL Workbench V8.0.

Comment: Why not just delete and ignore the table not found error? This eliminates race conditions where a table is created between the test and the truncate. Always consider this when doing SQL operations. Are you sure you don't want to use [truncate table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html)?

Comment: Oh, I actually can do that. You see, I was used to SQL Server way of checking things before before doing any table alteration. I didn't notice that MySQL can skip failed queries. Thank you ! Yes, changed DELETE to TRUNCATE.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Any language interating with SQL Server should be able to catch and an error. Glad you found this useful. I've added it as an answer.

Comment: Hi @danblack, are there any queries to run or any settings to be set to make mysql workbench ignore error queries? In some cases they stop at the error, in some, they proceed with the next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When delete an option is to ignore the table not found error. This eliminates race conditions where a table is created between the test and the truncate. Always consider this when doing SQL operations.